# include view based on href parameter in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

Maybe a basic problem, but - lets say there is a dropdown menu with several submenus:

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('news') }}">News</a>
<a href="{{ URL::route('articles') }}">Articles</a>
```

linked to different views:

```
(news.blade.php, articles.blade.php ...)
```

The index.blade.php looks like this:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('board')
    @include('files.index')
@endsection
```

Routes look like this:

```
<?php
Route::get('/', [
    'as' => 'home',
    'uses' => 'PagesController@home'
]);

Route::get('/articles', [
    'as' => 'articles',
    'uses' => 'PagesController@articles'
]);

Route::get('/news', [
    'as' => 'news',
    'uses' => 'PagesController@news'
]);
```

and the controller:

```
class PagesController extends Controller
{   
    public function home()
    {
       return view('files.index');
}

    public function articles()
    {
        return view('files.articles');
    }

    public function news()
    {
        return view('files.news');
    }
}
```

The problem is, that the 'board' section should load index.blade only at the beginning, but replace its content after a link from the menu is clicked.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create pages.blade.php view and in relative to it create folder "pages" with articles.blade.php, news.blade.php, home.blade.php and etc.

pages.blade.php :

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('board')
    @include('pages.'.$page_file)
@endsection
```

and here is Your controller:

```
class PagesController extends Controller
{   
    public function home()
    {
       return view('pages', ['page_file' => 'home']);
    }

    public function articles()
    {
        return view('pages', ['page_file' => 'articles']);
    }

    public function news()
    {
        return view('pages', ['page_file' => 'news']);
    }
}
```

Comment: yet, there is another, more "laravel" way, I´ve been suggested - not to include each view in index.blade, but rather to extend index.blade in each view and yield there´s content in index